# Shadowed method is not called

Tags: vb.net, inheritance, shadowing

I have a class which i realized will not always correctly instantiate and as a quick fix, i figured i'd subclass it and shadow a few methods so that the program can continue to run without exploding.  When i run the software, calls to the methods resolve to the base's implementations and not the subclass.  I'm using VB.NET with .NET 2.0.  Here is an example of what i'm trying to do:

```
Public Class SuperClass

  Public Sub New ()
    Dim type As Type = GetType(SubClass)
    If (Me.GetType() is type) Then
      //nothing
    Else
      //build real object
    EndIf
  End Sub

  Private Shared _Instance As SuperClass
  Public Shared ReadOnly Property Instance() As SuperClass
    Get
      If (_Instance Is Nothing) Then
        Try
          _Instance = New SuperClass()
        Catch ex As Exception
          Dim result As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show(text, caption, MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
          If (result = DialogResult.Retry) Then
            _Instance = New SuperClass()
            //this will probably cause problems of its own, but i'll cross that bridge later...
          Else
            _Instance = New SubClass()
          End If
        End Try

      End If
      Return _Instance
    End Get
  End Property

  Public Overridable Function MyFunction() As Integer
     Dim somethingReasonable As Integer //do something for real
     Return somethingReasonable
  End Function

End Class

Public Class SubClass
  Inherits SuperClass

  Public Sub New()
    //doesn't do what cause the exception in the first place
  End Sub

  Public Shadows Function MyFunction() As Integer
    //Do something safe
    Return -1
  End Function    

End Class
```

I'm not sure why the base class gets called during runtime.  When i inspect the object in the debugger it is clearly the SubClass type but the SuperClass methods get called.  Access to the object is through the Instance Property.

I'm sure i'm doing something wrong or making some wrong assumption but I can't figure out what.

Thanks,
brian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a method is shadowed rather than overridden, the shadowing methods will not be called when an instance is of subclass type -- the method which will be called is determined based on the compile-time type of the receiver rather than the run-time type.  This is the fundamental difference between shadowing and overriding.

Comment: so i should declare the sublcassed method as overrides rather than shadows and keep the overidable super class methods as they are?

Comment: Yes, declare the subclass method as `Overrides`.